# Big Sur - No "Create New Folder" option when using the finder to download files

Tags: finder, folders, big-sur

Since I've upgraded to Big Sur, the "Create New Folder" option has disappeared from Finder when it is opened in the context of downloading a file.

Here's an example:

1. A colleague sent me a file via Slack.
2. I'm clicking on the download button on Slack.
3. I'm browsing the Finder to the desired folder (I have writing permission in that folder)
4. I'm trying to create a new folder for that file. ISSUE - In the past I would have the ability to either (1) right click in an empty area and from the context menu create a new folder, or (2) from the top bar click on "Create New Folder". However, the first option is now impossible because even when I right click an empty space there's no such option, and the button for the second option simply doesn't exist.

Any ideas? Did Apple ruin finder like they've removed the calculator widget?

[image: Context Menu]

[image: Folder View Top Bar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not on Big Sur yet, so this is guesswork.
Potential reasons it's not working.

1. Those icons in the top bar have always been customisable - maybe it just reverted your icon choices.
   Finder, View Menu > Customise Toolbar… Actions contains the New Folder item.
2. Presumably you're not getting the right click option because you aren't seeing any free space, according to your 2nd pic.  (previous 30 days is not free space)
3. Cmd/Shift/N has been the key commend for New Folder for a long time.

Comment: Thanks! So here's what I found out:

1. I've re-added the "New Folder" item, it does appear in a regular Finder window but not in the context of downloading files from slack.
2. Indeed there's not a lot of free space visually, but even if I do find free space the only option in the context menu is "Show in Finder"
3. This works, which is great, but I was hoping the past options will be there, especially for non-power users.

I think the reason for why this happens is because Slack's download Finder opens in "Open" mode. Meaning, the button is not "Save" but rather "Open".

Comment: I actually hadn't realised initially that you were in a file-picker rather than Finder. I can confirm right-click doesn't work in file-pickers even in Mojave, neither does the customise toolbar - so as the other answer mentions this is a specific Slack bug, I guess you're left with cmd/shift/n for now.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Big Sur might've changed the context menu options, but **Slack** is to blame here since it has removed or hidden the [New Folder] button that has long existed.

You can confirm that the New Folder button is still present by saving a file in another program. At the bottom of the window, with the cancel and save buttons, a New Folder button will also be visible.